# match all words not starting with ':' Python regex

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

Hi I need to match `cola xx` from `:ca:cr:pr cola xx` but also be able to get `cola xx` when no `ca:cr:pr` occures. The number of tags starting with `:` can be different and their length too.

```
>>> string
':ca:cr:pr cola xx'
>>> re.findall("\w+", string)
['ca', 'cr', 'pr', 'cola', 'xx']
>>> re.findall(":\w+", string)
[':ca', ':cr', ':pr']
>>> re.findall("^(:\w+)", string)
[':ca']
```

I was trying to use also lookbehinds (http://runnable.com/Uqc1Tqv_MVNfAAGN/lookahead-and-lookbehind-in-regular-expressions-in-python-for-regex) but unsecesffully.

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\s\w+)(?!:)",string)
[' cola', ' xx']
>>> string="cola"
>>> re.findall(r"(\s\w+)(?!:)",string)
[]
```

That is when no tags, only `cola` it is not detected.

How can I improve my regex to work as expected?

desired examples once more:

`:c cola xx` -> `cola xx`

`:ca:c cola xx` -> `cola xx`

`:ca:cr:pr cola xx` -> `cola xx`

`cola xx` -> `cola xx`

`cola` -> `cola`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe something like this should work, if I understood your requirement correctly:

```
(?<!:)\b\w+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fC1wX4/1)

In code:

```
results = re.findall(r'(?<!:)\b\w+', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace all the words that begin with a colon, with nothing?

```
result = re.sub(r":\w+\b", "", subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
re.findall("(?<!:)(\w+)", string)
```

Comment: result = `['a', 'r', 'r', 'cola', 'xx']` This not what expected.

Comment: this is called negative lookbehind, you can read more here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: re.findall("(?<!:)(\w+)\s+|$", string)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
(?<!:)\w+(?:\s\w+)?
```